# Clicking Back button in browser Expires the page

Tags: c#

I'm using .NET c#.
I have a page for search which displays results on next page.
If you select a Course and that's not the one you want,you can click back IN BROWSER and go to search results to select another.
But clicking back in browser causes expired page.
I have a back button which works fine but clicking back in browser expirse the data.
How do i fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a cookie issue, but we can't be sure unless you provide some code on what you're doing.

Comment: Could be due to sending post data when selecting a search result. But as Michel said, some code example would be helpful

Comment: if you paste your code, it will be helpful for us to solve your problem.

Comment: i have a back button which works fine. But going back using a browser back expires the page.

Answer (score 0):

The data on the expired page are sent by POST method. It will require user to re-send the data. What you can do is change form method to GET (not always acceptable due to data size, security, url readability, logging and other factors). If GET is not an option, you should cache the POST result somehow (for example, putting it in a session) and make a redirect to a clean page which will take and display the cached result without requiring user to re-send it. When you return via Back button to that page, there will be no problem because that page is not generated directly by POST request, it only shows the results.

If the POST result is too big to be cached, then simply cache the input parameters and build a query based on them in the "clean" page. Once it has displayed the result, the Back button will work without the need to reload.